# using log4net with scoped properties

Tags: log4net

I'm using on an existing application log4net with seq target.
During a code workflow (which is calling different methods) I wish to save an id as a property in order to keep a reference to that id (when looking on Seq It's easier to understand what happened)

is there a way of using something as

```
using(var log = ........ properties)
{
     normal logging here
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Such a property can be stored on the [ThreadContext](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.12/release/sdk/log4net.ThreadContext.html) or [LogicalThreadContext](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.12/release/sdk/log4net.LogicalThreadContext.html) via eg

```
log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["someId"] = "foo";
```

and be included in a `LayoutPattern` via `%property{someId}`

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%logger | %level | %property{someId} | %message%newline" />
</layout>
```

The code below

```
ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger("SomeLogger");
logger.Info("Message 1");
```

then produces the following output

```
SomeLogger | INFO | foo | Message 1
```

**This contextual data can be stacked** because `Log4net` has the concept of  [context stacks](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/contexts.html).

> The stack is stored in a context property, therefore stacks have names and more than one stack can exist in the same context. A property value set in a narrower context would override a stack with the same property name set in a wider scoped context.
>
> The stack supports Push and Pop methods. As more contextual data is pushed onto the stack the stack grows. When the stack is rendered all the data pushed onto the stack is output with the most recent data to the right hand end of the string.
>
> As the stack is just an object stored in the context properties it is also rendered using the same PatternLayout syntax: %property{name}. Where name is the name of the stack.
>
> Calls the the stack's Push and Pop methods must be matched up so that each push has a corresponding pop. The Push method also returns an IDisposable object that will perform the required pop operation when it is disposed. This allows the C# using syntax to be used to automate the stack management.

A property value gets set on a stack  via `Push`, which returns an `IDisposable` object that removes this property value from the stack on disposal, eg

```
using (ThreadContext.Stacks["someId"].Push("bar"))
{
    logger.Info("Message 2");

    using (ThreadContext.Stacks["someId"].Push("baz"))
    {
        logger.Info("Message 3");
    }
}
```

with output

```
SomeLogger | INFO | bar | Message 2
SomeLogger | INFO | baz | Message 3
```